# List field focus issue in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Actually i have build an application,which has got customized list field items.The list of items surpasses the initial screen height.So we have to do a vertical scrolling.The prob is that,the focus is working up to the last element of the initial screen height,when the initial screen height is over,then scrolling the items shows white screen.I need the default blue focus in all the items.

Comment: I think we need to see some code.

Answer (score 1):

If you override the unfocus method to redraw your graphics the white screen will disapear

```
    protected void onUnfocus() {
        updateLayout();
    }
```